# What is the right way to use the tinyscrollbar update function with a jquery onclick event?

Tags: jquery, onclick, slidedown, slideup, tinyscrollbar

I have a list of states that displays or hides on click of a button using jquery `slideUp()` and `sideDown()` functions.

I'm trying to use [jquery tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) to add a custom scrollbar to it.

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ByteMyPixel/acLch/

I almost have it working, but am stuck - the tinyscrollbar shows on the second click event/`slideUp()` instead of `slideDown()`.

Any ideas on how to fix this so that the tinyscrollbar appears on `slideDown()`, and disappears on `slideUp()`?

Here is my code:

```
var oScrollbar1 = $('#scrollbar1');
oScrollbar1.tinyscrollbar();

$("a.button").click(function () {

oScrollbar1.tinyscrollbar_update();

    if ($("ul.scrolling").is(":hidden")) {
        $("ul.scrolling").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("ul.scrolling").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var oScrollbar1 = $('#scrollbar1');
    oScrollbar1.tinyscrollbar();

    $("a.button").click(function() 
    {
        $("ul.scrolling").slideToggle("slow", function()
        {                               
            oScrollbar1.tinyscrollbar_update();
        });
    });
```

This will fix your problem :)

Comment: Not sure why of the rollback after my edit no reason given by @Steven. The method 'tinyscrollbar_update' works on version 1.81 and version 2.0.3 of tinyscrollbar contains another method to update just called 'update'.

Answer (score 4):

Using the tinyscrollbar for jQuery like this:

```
var scroll = $("#add-widget-scroll").tinyscrollbar();
```

I did some research and I found that the "update" function can be accessed using this:

```
$(scroll).data().plugin_tinyscrollbar.update();
```

Comment: useful solution under version:2.1.9